# How to use TailwindCSS with NestJS?

Tags: nestjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I like using Tailwind CSS in my React and Laravel projects.
Now I've started learning NestJS and I want to use Tailwind CSS in my project, but I couldn't.
Since I couldn't find any results on Google, I'm asking you guys.

I would be grateful for any resource or your detailed answer.

The current state of my project is as follows. I don't know where I went wrong, TailwindCSS is not working.

Please note that I am just starting to learn NestJS.

### main.ts

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);

  app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));
  app.setBaseViewsDir(join(__dirname, '..', 'views'));
  app.setViewEngine('hbs');

  await app.listen(3000);
  console.log(`Application is running on: ${await app.getUrl()}`);
}
bootstrap();
```

### app.controller.ts

```js
import { Controller, Get, Render } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  @Get()
  @Render('index')
  root() {
    return { message: 'Hello world!' };
  }
}
```

### app.module.ts

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

### tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ['./views/*.hbs', './views/**/*.hbs'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

### webpack-hmr.config.js

```js
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const { RunScriptWebpackPlugin } = require('run-script-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function (options, webpack) {
  return {
    ...options,
    //entry: ['webpack/hot/poll?100', options.entry],
    entry: './src/main.ts',
    externals: [
      nodeExternals({
        allowlist: ['webpack/hot/poll?100'],
      }),
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
            { loader: 'style-loader' },
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                modules: true,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          use: [{ loader: 'ts-loader' }],
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      ...options.plugins,
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin({
        paths: [/\.js$/, /\.d\.ts$/],
      }),
      new RunScriptWebpackPlugin({ name: options.output.filename }),
    ],
  };
};
```

### index.hbs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>NestJS App With TailwindCSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/tailwind.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="w-full px-8 text-gray-700 bg-white flex">
      <h1 class="bg-slate-200">
      {{ message }}
      </h1>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

### and script command

```
"start:dev": "nest build --webpack --webpackPath webpack-hmr.config.js --watch",
```

Comment: NestJS is a backend framework and Tailwind is a frontend CSS framework. What are you talking about? Did you mean [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/)?

Comment: No, I'm talking about NestJS not NextJS. 
So, AdonisJS is a backend framework, but tailwindcss can be used. Example: https://www.cbsofyalioglu.com/code/adonisjs5-tailwind/

A solution like this for NestJS would be really great.

Comment: What's stopping you from using the same setup in Nest? Didn't really look like anything was tied to Adonis. Just a `postcss` processor and a `webpack` file for transpilation. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I added the sample codes to my first post. I don't understand why TailwindCSS isn't working.

Comment: Hey Mehmet, did you figure the solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the same issue but I didn't use **Webpack** and it works.

here are the steps I took:

Installing Tailwind using your favorite package manager

```
npm install -D tailwindcss
npx tailwindcss init
```

and because tailwind only looks for classes of HTML file i will limit it in configuration to only find them in `hbs` file like this:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./views/*.hbs', './views/**/*.hbs'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

like the way you configured it, then I made an `assets` folder in my root directory and a `tailwind.css` file in it:

**assets/tailwind.css:**

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

then I used this tailwind CLI command to build and extract the css to my `public` directory:

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./assets/tailwind.css -o ./public/main.css
```

> **NOTE:** you cant use hot reload (`--watch`) and run your backend (`nest start`) in one terminal so making your package.json like this
> won't work:
>
> `"start:dev": "nest start --watch && npx tailwindcss -i ./assets/tailwind.css -o ./public/css/main.css --watch"`

now the last step is to address the `main.css` to your hbs file:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="text-7xl">
    Hello world
  </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**I recommend developing your frontend in Next.js first and then pack and export it then integrate it with your backend.**

Comment: perfectly works, I need this to build simple admin dashboard.. NextJS and friends are pain the butt